# Let $a_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers. Let $E = [1,\infty)$, and $f =a_n$ if $n\leq x<n+1$.Show that $\int_Ef = \sum a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have the following problem;

Let $\{a_n\}$  be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers. Define the function $f$ on $E = [1,\infty)$ by setting $f(x) = a_n$ if  $n\leq x<n+1$. Show that $\int_Ef = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ .

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\chi_S$ be the characteristic function of a set $S$.
$$ f = 0\chi_{]-\infty,0[} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \chi_{[n,n+1[}
$$
$f$ may not be integrable if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does not converge. If $f$ is integrable,
$$\int_{[0,\infty[} f\,d\lambda = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_{[0,c]} f\,d\lambda
$$
By the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Thus its integral is
$$ \int_{[0,\infty[} f\,d\lambda = \int \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \chi_{[n,n+1[ \cap [0,\infty[}\,d\lambda = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \lambda([n,n+1[) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
$$
as desired.